# calling JQuery show/hide on id in parent page

Tags: jquery-selectors, wicket

I'm trying to get this to work, in a Wicket renderHead-method the parameter IHeaderResponse response is passing a javascript, to show respectively hide links in the calling parent page.
This is a part of a mobile web app served via an Apache Tomcat server.

StartPage.html, (the calling parent page, where the links to be hidden/shown is)

```
<li class="ui-block-e">
    <a wicket:id="logoutlink" id="logout" href="#" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-corner-   all ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-top">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Logga ut</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-custom"></span>
           </span>
<a wicket:id="loginlink" id="login" href="/domain/mobile/login" data-theme="a"    class="ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-top">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
    <span class="ui-btn-text">Logga in</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-custom"></span>
    </span>
     </a>
</li>
```

LoginRedirectPage.java, (the page containing the redirecting js)

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
log.info("Redirecting to " + redirectUrl);//to check via log

// if the parent is the mobile app..
response.renderOnDomReadyJavascript(
"if(parent && parent.$ && parent.$.mobile){" +
"parent.$('#logout').show();" +
"parent.$('#login').hide();" +
"parent.history.go(-2);" +                  
"console.log('redirecting with jqm "+redirectUrl+"');" +//logging
"}");
```

However, (saw this coming huh !?),

the lines "parent.$('#logout').show();" and "parent.$('#login').hide();"

does what they are supposed to in a browser (via a PC), the logout link is enabled and the login link is hidden ( if the user is logged in).

**But** while doing this via an Android phone the links is **not** shown/hidden as they are supposed to, the login link is still sitting there. As if i wasn't logged in, although the logs shows that i'm logged in.

The constant "redirectUrl" point in this case back to the StartPage.html.

By the way, i also tried to use some old-style js, ex. "parent.document.getElementById('logout').style.display='block';", to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

//Kalle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's been a while, but here is what i finally did to get it to work out for me, at this point i want to thank jbrookover for his quick answer.
The solution however turned out to be a more "oldfasioned" one.

In the case of using JQueryMobile, pages are stored in a cache, in order to reduce the cost of loading pages.
This meant that the page from where one start also is stored in the cache, thus storing the way the different links are rendered in the Android phone, and the solution was taking advantage of oldfasioned HTML.
By incorporating the following in the head section of the startpage,

```
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

this page was never stored in the JQueryMobile's cache, and the javscript code,

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
log.info("Redirecting to " + redirectUrl);//to check via log

// if the parent is the mobile app..
response.renderOnDomReadyJavascript(
"if(parent && parent.$ && parent.$.mobile){" +
"parent.$('#logout').show();" +
"parent.$('#login').hide();" +
"parent.history.go(-2);" +                  
"console.log('redirecting with jqm "+redirectUrl+"');" +//logging
"}");
```

was actually taking effect.

Hopefully this may come to use for someone else having an issue with the JQueryMobile caching at some point.

Sinc.

Answer (score 0):

Wicket is freely available to rewrite your element IDs, especially if you are doing anything complicated with Ajax.  However, it makes those IDs available to you for use in such things like this.  Here would be your java code:

```
Link logoutLink = new Link("logoutlink");
logoutLink.setOutputMarkupId(true); // Explicitly create the ID attribute
add(logoutLink);
```

Then, when you render your javascript, adjust that line to look like this:

```
"parent.$('#" + logoutLink.getMarkupId() + "').show();"
```

Obviously, you'll have to put the `logoutLink` variable in a scope that is accessible to `renderHead` method.

You can confirm that this is indeed the issue by looking at your rendered code.  The ID has probably changed from "logout" to something like "logoutlink12"

Comment: Hi! ok sorry for not answering up until now, as i'm not sure as to if the logoutLink is rendered in a default fashion (as you proposed, "logoutlink12" instead of "logoutlink"), being a problem as how to view the rendered html in the Android phone running the app in question. I would have to try to find a way to get hold of the rendered html, in order to properly view what is passed back to the parent page (that is, what is manipulating the logout/login tags on the parent page), any tips as to how to view the rendered html in the Android phone, is kindly apreciated. //Kalle

Comment: I'm sure there are a few ways (that I don't readily know as I haven't worked on Android).  However, you could always just change your javascript conditional and render said page to regular browsers temporarily, just to check the markup.  Regardless, my point still stands.  I'd bet money that your markup ID is being modified by wicket and cannot be assumed to be `$('#logout')`.  Using `logoutLink.getMarkupId()` is common behavior when working with javascript.